# Dynamics CRM Sandbox Errors when Plug-in Executes Process

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've extensively searched the forums for an answer to this. I've been periodically getting sandbox related errors thrown for a CRM Plug-in we use. It seems like the plug-in process retries multiple times and then does finish but it errors out 6,7,8 times before it finally successfully executes. Can anyone help me with this? We have Dynamics CRM 2013 On Premise.

Error is below:

```
Sync workflow failed with error message - Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: The plug-in execution failed because no Sandbox Hosts are currently available. Please check that you have a Sandbox server configured and that it is running.
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #8594C280Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147204722</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>The plug-in execution failed because no Sandbox Hosts are currently available. Please check that you have a Sandbox server configured and that it is running.
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #8594C280</Message>
  <Timestamp>2017-09-06T18:13:03.6732168Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault>
    <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>System.IO.PipeException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #30BA0652</Message>
    <Timestamp>2017-09-06T18:13:03.6732168Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <TraceText>
[Mkto_Pack_Plugins: Mkto_Pack_Plugins.ProcessAssign]
[f248c719-a487-e111-98ea-005056810010: Mkto_Pack_Plugins.ProcessAssign: Assign of lead]

</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Invoke(Activity activity, IDictionary`2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity workflow, IDictionary`2 inputs, TimeSpan timeout, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.SynchronousRuntime.SynchronousWorkflowActivityHost.ExecuteWorkflowUsingInvoker(Activity workflow, ICommonWorkflowContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.SynchronousRuntime.SynchronousWorkflowActivityHost.StartWorkflow(WorkflowActivationData activationData, ICommonWorkflowContext context)
, error code - -2147204722
```

Comment: I should also mention that my IT team has assured me that the service is running and properly configured.

Comment: A couple thoughts... do you have a dev environment to try it in? Also, perhaps create a Dynamics 365 online trial and try it there. If it's compiled against the v6.1 SDK DLL's it should work online without recompiling.